# Convert a List of Object/Strings into substrings separated by comma

Tags: c#, .net

Please help on converting a list of objects got from DB into substrings separated by a comma

Take for example I have a sample code below:

```
List<string> CategoryNames = new List<string>();
CategoryNames.Add("myName1");
CategoryNames.Add("myName2");
CategoryNames.Add("myName3");
```

I want to convert CategoryNames into a format like this

> "myName1","myName2","myName3"

From the above CatgoryNames happen to be retrieved from db.

```
var categoryNames = _context.BillingCategory.ToList();
```

How do I convert the `categoryNames` into substrings as shown above?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `"myName1,myName2,myName3"`?

Comment: Just to doublecheck: Do you really want the result to contain quotes as well like this: "myName1","myName2","myName3" or you just want to get something like this?: "myName1 , myName2 , myName3"

Comment: `string.Join` seems like an answer....  but please clarify requirements

Comment: Yes i want the format to contain quotes like ``` "myName1","myName2","myName3"```

Comment: string.Join("," CategoryNames); would only give me a format like this "myName1,myName2,myName3"

Comment: Guys, please I want the output to contain the quotes too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) method by combining with LINQ for preserving the quotes before joining:

```
var result = String.Join(",", CategoryNames.Select(item => $"\"{item}\""));
```

And here is the clearer version of the code if you don't linke singleliner:

```
var QuotedCategroyNames = CategoryNames
    .Select(item => $"\"{item}\"");

var result = String.Join(",", QuotedCategroyNames);
```

Comment: working, but the output is this  `\"myName1\",\"myName2\",\"myName3\"` is this how it should be

Comment: Yep, if you are looking from the IDE, it will be shown that way (because it escapes the quote character there). But you can do Console.WriteLine(result); or put the result in the UI, and you'll see the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ `Select` to enclose all names in quotes, then `string.Join` to merge back into a comma separated string.

```
string.Join(',', CategoryNames.Select(n => '"' + n + '"'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) and concat with the double quotes character :

```
var serialized = $@"""{ string.Join(@""",""", CategoryNames) }"""; // "myName1","myName2","myName3"
```

[Try it yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8Th5CF)